# Access denied finding property "vendor.perf.iop_v3.enable"

Tags: android

Today I started implementing an API into my app, when the app is loading it shows activity (a loading dialog) for a second. Then the following message starts spamming in logcat:

```
10-04 15:54:33.094 27832-27832/nl.berris.roy.raspberrypiproject E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.perf.iop_v3.enable"
10-04 15:54:33.094 27832-27832/nl.berris.roy.raspberrypiproject E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.perf.iop_v3.enable.debug"
```

Logcat is set to error level with filter on selected app only. This is the only output that is given.

After this message spams for 5 seconds the app will force stop without any message. I cannot find anything about this on Google. Does anyone have an answer to why this is showing?

My implementations in gradle:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.3'

implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

I am using Retrofit2 to make an api call. I did comment out the API code and the app still crashed. Still api call runs async.

Only thing that happends in the app right now is an Activity that opens up an Fragment. In this fragment is a recyclerview with adapter attached. Also a "fail" MaterialDialog will show because the API call failed. Everything loads, even the "fail" dialog. Which is created *after* the api call is made (and fails). Then after a couple of seconds the app stops. And displays the error message as shown above.

Comment: I have the same logs on my OnePlus 6 on Android 9. Have you found what causes these logs ?